# Can Synthesist Summoners apply evolutions to the Summoner's natural attacks?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, summoner, eidolon

I'm a bit confused here. Since the Eidolon and Summoner are fused together as a Synthesist, could I apply an evolution like reach to one of my Summoner's own natural attacks? Or would I have to wait until level 10 to use Aspect?

Answer (score 4):

### You have access to all your own and your Eidolon's attacks.

From the [Synthesist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner/archetypes/paizo-summoner-archetypes/synthesist)'s Fused Eidolon class feature:

> The synthesist uses the eidolon’s base attack bonus, and gains the eidolon’s armor and natural armor bonuses and modifiers to ability scores. The synthesist also gains access to the eidolon’s special abilities and the eidolon’s evolutions. The synthesist is still limited to the eidolon’s maximum number of natural attacks.

You can still use your own Natural Attack(s) while Fused, but you cannot do so beyond the normal Eidolon limit on Natural Attacks.

### However, you cannot apply Evolutions to your own attacks.

The Reach Evolution must be 'attached' to a Natural Attack selected for your Eidolon. You (the Summoner) don't have Evolution Points to spend, your Eidolon does. You must select something your Eidolon has. Ref:

> **One of an eidolon’s attacks** is capable of striking at foes at a distance. Pick one attack. The eidolon’s reach with that attack increases by 5 feet.

### Using Aspect does allow what you want.

You would be able to select your own Natural Attack with the Evolution Points diverted by Aspect. The Reach Evolution has no requirement that you wouldn't qualify for.

Answer (score 2):

While the synthesist and eidolon do fuse, they're still separate entities as far as evolution points are concerned. The eidolon's evolution points can only be spent on the eidolon, with the exception of the aspect ability.

Additionally, since the eidolon effectively **replaces** the synthesist's physical body while fused, you won't be able to use your summoner's own natural attacks while the eidolon is summoned. You'd have to apply the reach evolution to one of the eidolon's natural attacks, and attack with that instead.

Comment: But the actual text says: "The synthesist wears the eidolon like translucent, living armor. The eidolon mimics all of the synthesist’s movements" Doesn't that mean the Eidolon adapts to the physical body of the Summoner? So if the summoner had a tail or something it would go around it and move with it

Comment: That text is a bit misleading. Keep in mind that the eidolon doesn't need to be the same size as the summoner, or even the same general body plan. A human synthesist can have a serpentine eidolon with no limbs, after all. The summoner's own body is more or less ignored by the ability. So while it's perfectly reasonable to "skin" the eidolon as sharing your summoner's natural attacks for fluff purposes, you'd still have to spend the evolution points in order to use those attacks while merged.